# R: how to make a for cycle work correctly with a list of list and write a word document with output?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Goodmorning to all members of the community,

I'm working with several txt files and I have to make several analysis on it and wrote their results on a word text. My data are like this:

```
list.8


[[1]]
[1] "Bar.L2.txt" "Bar.L5.txt" "Bar.L6.txt"

[[2]]
[1] "Cart.L2.txt" "Cart.L5.txt" "Cart.L6.txt"
```

So as you can see for each patient I have 3 txt files and I write this for cycle to create a plot for first patient L2 and first patient L5 txt and write the result in a word document. Then do the same with the second patient.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ReporteRs)
for (i in 1:length(list.8)){
#Analyze the first element of the list and make a plot
data<-read.table(list.8[[i]][1],header=T)
names(data) <- sub("_mean", "", names(data))
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(data,gsub,pattern="k__Bacteria;p__",replacement=""))
df4<-df2[,c(1,6,7)]
col5=grep("CTRL",names(df4))
df4<-cbind(df4[-col5],df4[col5])
mdf4<-melt(df4,id.vars='OTU')
means=ddply(mdf4,c("variable","OTU"),summarize,mean=mean(as.numeric(value)))
plot1=ggplot(data=means, aes(x=variable, y=mean)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = OTU),position = 'fill',stat="identity", colour="black")+
scale_fill_manual(values=mycol)+ theme(text = element_text(size=8,colour="black"), axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black",face="bold"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black",face="bold"),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="black"),panel.background=element_blank(),axis.line=element_line(colour="black"))+
guides(fill=guide_legend(title=""))
#Analyze the second element of the list and make a plot
data2<-read.table(list.8[[i]][2],header=T)
data2$OTU=sub(".*;f__", "", data2$OTU)
names(data2) <- sub("_mean", "", names(data2))
df5<-subset(data2,P<=0.05) 
df5$OTU=sub(".*;Other", "", df5$OTU)
df5=df5[!df5$OTU %in% family,]
df6= df5[!(is.na(df5$OTU) | df5$OTU==""), ] 
plot2=ggplot(data=means2, aes(x=variable, y=mean)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = OTU),stat="identity", colour="black")+
scale_fill_manual(values=mycol)+ theme(text = element_text(size=8,colour="black"), axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black",face="bold"),axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black",face="bold"),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="black"),panel.background=element_blank(),axis.line=element_line(colour="black"))+
guides(fill=guide_legend(title=""))
#transfer all in a word document
doc<-docx(template="../Template2.docx")%>%
     addSection(ncol = 2, space_between = 0.35)%>%        
     addSection(ncol = 2, space_between = 0.35)%>%
   addPlot(fun=print,x=plot1,vector.graphic = FALSE,width=3.5,height=3,par.properties = parLeft())%>%
   addColumnBreak() %>% 
   addPlot(fun=print,x=plot2,vector.graphic = FALSE,width=3.5,height=3,par.properties = parRight())%>% 
   addSection(ncol = 1 ) %>% 
     addParagraph("") %>%    
writeDoc(doc,file = paste0(list.8[[i]][1],"_Referto.docx"))
}
```

Unfortunatly  i get a problem in my results: In fact for the first patient it make the right word output, but then for the second patient it only changes the plot1 correctly with data for the second patient while for plot2 it always maintain data from the first patient and not from the second...and so on.... does someone know how can i tell him to correct it? thanks a lot

Comment: As no one can reproduce your loop and your code is so wordy and busy you will get no help. I recommend to loop by hand through your code, e.g. safe `i<-1`, then `i<-2` and check all parameters if there are correct.

Comment: I see, thank for your suggestion Jimbou